# joi_1.default.validate is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, joi

I want to validate my Express routes before calling the controller logic. I use joi and created a validator which is able to validate the Request object against the schema object

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import joi, { SchemaLike, ValidationError, ValidationResult } from '@hapi/joi';
import { injectable } from 'inversify';

@injectable()
export abstract class RequestValidator {
    protected validateRequest = (validationSchema: SchemaLike, request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction): void => {
        const validationResult: ValidationResult<Request> = joi.validate(request, validationSchema, {
            abortEarly: false
        });

        const { error }: { error: ValidationError } = validationResult;

        if (error) {
            response.status(400).json({
                message: 'The request validation failed.',
                details: error.details
            });
        } else {
            next();
        }
    }
}
```

Next I created a deriving class which creates the validationSchema and calls the `validateRequest` method. For the sake of simplicity I will show the "deleteUserById" validation

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import joi, { SchemaLike } from '@hapi/joi';
import { injectable } from 'inversify';

import { RequestValidator } from './RequestValidator';

@injectable()
export class UserRequestValidator extends RequestValidator {
    public deleteUserByIdValidation = async (request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<void> => {
        const validationSchema: SchemaLike = joi.object().keys({
            params: joi.object().keys({
                id: joi.number().required(),
            })
        });

        this.validateRequest(validationSchema, request, response, next);
    }
}
```

**Important note:** I create the `SchemaLike` that way because some routes might have `params, body, query` which need to get validated in one run.

When calling the Route

> DELETE /users/1

the validation always fails. I get this error

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: joi_1.default.validate is
>   not a function

The error occurs with every validation, whether called correctly or not. Does someone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hit the same problem when using `express-joi-validation`.

If it's ok for you to use version 15, downgrade Joi will make it.

```
npm uninstall --save @hapi/joi
npm install --save @hapi/joi@15.0.3
```

Comment: Sorry, downvoting because this is not actual anymore. v15 is deprecated. API is changed. Check Eran Hammer's answer, which is correct.

Comment: Downvoting it. You shouldn't have to use deprecated APIs.

Answer (score 36):

You can fix it by changing:

```js
joi.validate(request, validationSchema)
```

to:

```js
validationSchema.validate(request)
```

**`joi.validate()` Is no longer supported in v16**. It is clearly documented in the API docs and release notes.

Answer (score 23):

Update version of joi doesn't work with `Joi.validate(req.body,schema);` No need to use the object separately. Use this as following. It Worked for me smoothly. Do let me know if I am wrong at anything:

```
const Joi = require('@hapi/joi');

const schema = Joi.object({
    name:Joi.string().min(3).required(),
    email:Joi.string().min(4).required().email(),
    password:Joi.string().min(6).required()
});





router.post('/register', async (req,res) => {


    //updated joi
    
   // This is a shorter version
    const { error } = schema.validate(req.body);

    // Error in response

    res.send(error.details[0].message);


    // WORKING WITH DEPRECATED VERSION
    // const Validation = Joi.validate(req.body,schema);
    // res.send(Validation);
```

Answer (score 15):

I experienced `joi.validate()` is not a function also. I checked their documentation and got a fix for it.

```
    const Joi = require('@hapi/joi');

const schema = Joi.object({
    name:Joi.string().min(6).required(),
    email:Joi.string().min(6).required().email(),
    password:Joi.string().min(6).required()
});

router.post('/register',  (req, res) => {

    // VALIDATE BEFORE SAVING A USER 
    const Validation = schema.validate(req.body);
    res.send(Validation);

    
})
```

This works as expected and gives no further error.

Answer (score 7):

You can fix it by changing
`Joi.validate(request, validationSchema)` to `validationSchema.validate(request)` As `Joi.validate()` is no longer supported in v16.

For new version

```
const schema = Joi.object({ name: Joi.string() .min(6) .required(),
email: Joi.string() .min(6) .required() .email(),
password: Joi.string() .min(6) .required() });

const validation = schema.validate(req.body);
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of downgrading the `Joi` version it's better to quickly have a look at API of the newest version and check the correct way of using it.

[Here](https://hapi.dev/family/joi/?v=16.1.7#example) is the link to the latest Joi API at the moment (16.1.7), where you can see an example of using `validate`.

Also to make sure you know what has been changed in next version of a lib that you use, it is good to have a look at the Release notes, [here is a link to a Joi version 16 Release notes](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/issues/2037) where you can see all the changes/new features, and FYI you can see info about `validate` method:

> Remove Joi.validate() and Joi.describe() (call direct on schema instead) (#1941)

Comment: This answer worked. In schema put const schemaName= Joi.object({ and then your normal schema data: Note the Joi.object is needed. When calling it, just use schemaName.validate(req.body) [instead of the old version Joi.validate(req.body, schemaName)]

Answer (score 3):

For the new version

```
const schema = Joi.object({ name: Joi.string() .min(6) .required(),
email: Joi.string() .min(6) .required() .email(),
password: Joi.string() .min(6) .required() });

const validation = schema.validate(req.body);
res.send(validation);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some fixed with snippet codes :)

Install below npm package.

```
npm install --save @hapi/joi@15.0.3
```

req-validator.js file

```
const Joi = require("@hapi/joi");

const registerValidation = data => {

const schema = {
    name : Joi.string().min(4).required(),
    email: Joi.string().min(4).required().email(),
    password: Joi.string().min(4).required()
};
return Joi.validate(data,schema);

}
module.exports.registerValidation = registerValidation;
```

finally, calling the validation method in the controller.

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const {registerValidation}  = require("./req-validator")

router.post("/register",async(req,res)=> {

const {error} =  registerValidation(req.body);
if(error){
    return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
}
 // logic to save in DB....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply You can check whether you have @hapi/joi installed and required in your file

and for validation use This approach.

```js
const schema= Joi.object().keys({

    name: Joi.string().min(6).required(),
    email: Joi.string().min(6).email(),
    password: Joi.string().min(6).required()
});

 const validation = schema.validate(req.body);
    if(validation.error){
        res.status(400).send(validation.error.details[0].message);
        return ;
    }
```

I think This is gonna work

Answer (score 1):

```
Following works with the latest version ("@hapi/joi": "^17.1.1"):

    const Joi = require("@hapi/joi");

    const schema = Joi.object({
      name: Joi.string().min(6).required(),
      email: Joi.string().min(6).required().email(),
      password: Joi.string().min(6).required(),
    });
    
  router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  const { error } = schema.validate(req.body);

  if (error) {
    res.json({ ErrorMessage: error.details[0].message });
  } else {
    res.json({ message: "valid data" });
  }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

**npm i joi**

**joi v17.4.x**
resource: https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.4.2

```
const schema = Joi.object({
  email: Joi.string().email().required(),
  password: Joi.string().required().min(5),
});

 const result = schema.validate(YourRequest.body);
```

Comment: Your formatting is confusing me so much that I cannot tell wether this is code only or a "test" random characters post. Lets assume code-only.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Linked content is not considered part of an answer, so this is still code-only. And unreadable or confusingly formatted. Please write some prose with explanation and try for more somber formatting.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Create your validate function like this

```
const validateUser = function (user) {
  const schema = Joi.object({
    username: Joi.string().min(5).max(50),
    email: Joi.string().required().email().min(5).max(255),
    password: Joi.string().required().min(5).max(1024),
  });

  return schema.validate(user);
};
```

You will get the error by

```
const { error } = validateUser({ email: 'admin' });
```

And the error message by

```
const message = error.details[0].message;
```

Answer (score 0):

// Get the instance on schema defination

```
function validate(model, object, scope) {
  const schema = getSchema(model, scope);
  return schema.validate(object);
}
```

// actual middleware factory to validate

```
module.exports = function ValidationMiddleware(model, scope) {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    const validationResult = validate(model, req.body, scope);
    if (validationResult.error) {
      throw new Error(validationResult.error.details[0].message);
    } else {
      next();
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, code-only answers have limited usefulness for future visitors to this question. Consider editing in some explanation on how and/or why your code answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
const schema = Joi.object({
    name: Joi.string().min(6).required(),
    email: Joi.string().min(6).email(),
    password: Joi.string().min(6).required()
})
```

insted of const schema = {...}

and Validate through this:

```
const validate = schema.validate(req.body)
```

instead of Joi.validate(req.body,schema)

Answer (score 0):

Here is something straight out of a project I'm working on, using Joi 17.3.0:

```
PDFCreatorController.exportAsPDF = (req, res) => {
  const data = req.body
  const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    svgDataToExport: Joi.string().required()
  })
  const isValidPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
    const validation = schema.validate(req.body)
    if (validation.error) {
      res.status(422).json({
        status: 'error',
        message: error,
        data: data
      })
    } else {
      resolve(data)
    }
  })
  isValidPromise.then(inputDataFromUser => {
    try {
      const exportAsPDF = PDFCreatorModel.exportAsPDF(inputDataFromUser)
      exportAsPDF.then(data => {
        res.json(data)
      })
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
      return res.status(500).json(error)
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to  Updated version of **JOI** Package we are all facing this error but here is the solution of that. In Node.js when we facing this error we can solve it applying below solution.

```
// Example : Here we try to validate user's data
// User's POST Api 

const schema = Joi.object({
    name: Joi.string().min(1).required(),
    email:  Joi.string().required().email(),
    password: Joi.string().min(8).max(12).required(),
    isEmailVerified: Joi.boolean().required(),
    forgotPasswordToken: Joi.string().required(),
    isDeleted: Joi.boolean().required()
});
try {
    const value = await schema.validateAsync(req.body);
}
catch (err) {
    return res.status(400).send(err);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Lower down the version of joi. to 13.0.1 it will work.
in terminal npm i joi@13.0.1.
2.after install check. dependencies in package. Json file.